# Is it possible to roll back a given flag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flags

I just want to know is there any way to roll back our flag.

I flagged a question for moderator attention. But after the post owner updation, it seems it is Q&A format only. So i want to roll back my flag.

Is it possible? If it is possible, how can i get back my flag?

Comment: No we can't take back our flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. Don't worry, though, a few rejected flags doesn't make much of a difference. With some luck, the mod may notice that the post was edited, and will mark it as helpful anyway.

Comment: Never happened to me, sad to say. Always get declined after an edit that fixes the issue at hand. =)

Comment: Not that it's any big deal. The goal is not to score 100% on flags, it is to improve the site. Net win for everyone if the flag becomes obsolete. @J.Steen

Comment: @CodyGray Of course. I never take a "properly" declined flag as a loss. In one way or another, the post was improved. =)

Comment: @CodyGray: Welcome back to meta! :)

Comment: @Manishearth - Same happened to me. I flagged [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15847135/1369235) as SPAM (see it's revision) but was declined after he edited. :(